# How to make dns resolve faster

Tags: dns, ping

I changed name server of one domain.

Then I flush dns

```
root@host [~]# /etc/init.d/named restart
Stopping named:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting named:                                            [  OK  ]
root@host [~]# ping wallpaperx.org
PING wallpaperx.org (76.73.5.22) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 76.73.5.22: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=36.0 ms
64 bytes from 76.73.5.22: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=36.7 ms
64 bytes from 76.73.5.22: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=35.9 ms
64 bytes from 76.73.5.22: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=35.9 ms
```

Well, ping still points to the old server.

Why?

Comment: Pretty sure it takes time (up to a few hours) for a DNS change to propagate to all DNS servers, and there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to understand Time to Live ( TTL ) in DNS

#### DNS TTL

TTL is an acronym for Time To Live and refers to the capability of the DNS servers to cache DNS records. It represents the amount of time that a DNS record for a certain host remains in the cache memory of a DNS server after the latter has located the host's matching IP address.

If your DNS is cached by your ISP DNS server or Public DNS Server then you can to wait as per TTL values. If you restart the local DNS Server then it will not affect because it's taking the answer from another DNS server.

If you want to override that urgently then then you can add those entry in `/etc/hosts` file and run `rndc flushname wallpaperx.org` .

You don't need to restart the whole DNS server, it will flush all other sites from memory, and it will increase load on your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `nscd` running, you have to flush its name-resolver-cache as well: `nscd -i hosts`. Apart from that a named-restart will not do much.

Is this a primary DNS-server? Then the generation-number has to be raised after you changed the contents of a zone.

A secondary DNS-server? Then you might force to reload the corresponding zones before the TTL expires.